# Sum values in a column based on values in other columns; Part 1

Tags: r, dataframe

In my table below, the first column is binary character (A & B). The second column is numeric:

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |

I like to sum the values in the second column based on the values in the first column, like this:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |
| A | 3 |  |
| A | 4 |  |
| A | 2 | 10 |
| B | 1 |  |
| B | 1 |  |
| B | 2 |  |
| B | 3 | 7 |
| A | 2 |  |
| A | 4 | 6 |
| B | 2 |  |
| B | 4 |  |
| B | 5 | 11 |

Can you please help me with it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df<- data.frame('V1' = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','B','B','B'), 'V2' = c(1,3,4,2,1,1,2,3,2,4,2,4,5))
df$V3<-NA
helper=data.frame('H',0,0)
names(helper)<-c('V1','V2','V3')
df<-rbind(df, helper)
c=0
for (i in (1:(length(df$V1)-1))) {
  if (df$V1[i]==df$V1[i+1]) {
    c = c+df$V2[i]
  }
  else {
    df$V3[i]<- c+df$V2[i]
    c=0
    next
  }
}

df<- head(df,-1)
```

**Output**

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NA |
| A | 3 | NA |
| A | 4 | NA |
| A | 2 | 10 |
| B | 1 | NA |
| B | 1 | NA |
| B | 2 | NA |
| B | 3 | 7 |
| A | 2 | NA |
| A | 4 | 6 |
| B | 2 | NA |
| B | 4 | NA |
| B | 5 | 11 |

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you very much. But immediately I can see in your code that the last row is not working. Can you please fix it too?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will fix it.

Comment: It is fixed. The helper row fixes the endpoint discrepancy, and then is dropped in the end.

Comment: yes, perfect! I'll apply it to my dataset now. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Dear j__carlson, I have another question. I have made a new question in PART2. I wonder if you can look at my new question? It is a continuation of PART1 (this question). I have got an answer from Mrs. Rosalie but her answer changes the structure of my Table. I like to keep the structure of my Table untouched. The link of PART2 is her: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68772466/sum-values-in-a-column-based-on-values-in-other-columns-part-2/68773085#68773085

Comment: @FarshidOwrang I have answered question Part 2. Please let me know if you have any questions about the solution.

Comment: Yes, yes, I have checked it fast and it seems it is working well. Thank you very much  j__carlson. I will mark it as ACCEPTED. Thank you!