# Sum values in a column based on values in other columns; Part 2

Tags: r

In my table below, the first column is ternary character (A, B & C). The second column is the numeric values. For C we have NA in the Table: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuYpf.png)

As in Part 1, I like to sum the values in the second column based on the values in the first column as well, but this time like this: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSUik.png)

Her is my data frame:

```
df <-data.frame('V1' = c('A',   'A',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'C'),'V2' = c(1,    3,  4,  2,  1,  1,  2,  3,  NA, 2,  4,  2,  4,  5,  NA, 3,  3,  2,  2,  NA, 5,  5,  2,  3,  NA))
```

Observe that the value of C is:

`C = (Sum(A) -sum(B))`.

Can you please help me with this too? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think these are same pictures

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have fixed it. Can you please look at this again? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
df <-data.frame('V1' = c('A',   'A',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'C'),'V2' = c(1,    3,  4,  2,  1,  1,  2,  3,  NA, 2,  4,  2,  4,  5,  NA, 3,  3,  2,  2,  NA, 5,  5,  2,  3,  NA))
df$V3<-NA
helper=data.frame('H',0,0)
names(helper)<-c('V1','V2','V3')
df<-rbind(df, helper)
c=0
for (i in (1:(length(df$V1)-1))) {
  if (df$V1[i]==df$V1[i+1]) {
    c = c+df$V2[i]
  }
  else {
    df$V3[i]<- c+df$V2[i]
    c=0
    next
  }
}

df<- head(df,-1)

a<-na.omit(df$V3[df$V1=="A"])
b<-na.omit(df$V3[df$V1=="B"])
c=a-b
df$V3[df$V1=="C"]<-c
```

**Note:** This solution will not match the pictured table due to the fact that the provided data frame is not an exact match to the pictured table. Also you will notice that this solution is the same as Part 1 except with the addition of the bottom 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option, not very direct, but I think it does what you want!

```
library(tidyverse)

# Creating here a unique index "ind"
df <- df %>% mutate(ind = with(rle(V1), rep(ave(values, values, FUN = seq_along), lengths)),
              ind = paste(V1,ind,sep = "_"))

# Sum up by group
df <- df %>% group_by(ind, V1) %>% summarise(sum = sum(V2))

# Substract A - B
# First, get the index back
df <- df %>% separate(ind, c(NA, "ind"), sep = "_") 
# Then, manipulate a bit the dataframe to get B - A
df <- df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = ind, names_from = V1, values_from = sum)%>%
  mutate(C = A - B)

# go back to initial structure
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = A:C, names_to = "V1", values_to = "sum")

# you can get rid of the index column
df %>% select(!ind)
```

Best,
Rosalie

Comment: Thank you very much Rosalie! I will test it during the weekend!

Comment: Dear Rosalie, It seems that I lose the structure of my Table (df) after "sum". Is it possible to get the results (A-B) in front of the C in the V3 column without losing the structure of my Table?